# flutter How to update bool data using switchlisttile to cloudfirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save boolean values to Firebase cloud firestore in switchlisttile section. I'm very new to flutter. I want to save boolean values to cloud firestore.
when I choose to switchtile on or off I want the on or off value to be boolean and save to firestore

I've been stuck on this issue for a very long time now and I can't seem to find a solution to it.

```
class Dashboard_Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Dashboard_Screen> createState() => _Dashboard_ScreenState();
}

class _Dashboard_ScreenState extends State<Dashboard_Screen> {
  //switch settingpage
  bool _isSwitchedOn_water = false;
  bool _isSwitchedOn_liquidfertilizer = false;
  bool _isSwitchedOn_light = false;

  //controlpage
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  late PageController _pageController;

  //set initstate
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  // dispose
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // drawer: Navigationbar(),
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Dashboard'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade900,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: (() {
                }),
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              )
            ]),
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("outputtest").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              return Scaffold(
                body: PageView(
                  controller: _pageController,
                  onPageChanged: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  children: [
                    //set page 
                    //PAGE DASHBOARD
                   ****
                    
                    // PAGE SETTING
                    // ---------------page setting-----------//
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: SwitchListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.green.shade600,
                              title: Text(
                                _isSwitchedOn_water ? 'water' : 'water',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: (Text(
                                _isSwitchedOn_water ? 'on' : 'off',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                              )),
                              value: _isSwitchedOn_water,
                              onChanged: (bool value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isSwitchedOn_water = value;
                                  (print(value));
                                });
                              },
                              secondary: const Icon(Icons.water_drop),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: SwitchListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.green.shade600,
                              title: Text(
                                _isSwitchedOn_liquidfertilizer
                                    ? 'liquidfertilizer'
                                    : 'liquidfertilizer',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: (Text(
                                _isSwitchedOn_liquidfertilizer ? 'on' : 'off',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                              )),
                              value: _isSwitchedOn_liquidfertilizer,
                              onChanged: (bool value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isSwitchedOn_liquidfertilizer = value;
                                  (print(value));
                                });
                              },
                              secondary: const Icon(Icons.water_outlined),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: SwitchListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.green.shade600,
                              title: Text(
                                _isSwitchedOn_light ? 'lightbulb' : 'lightbulb',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: (Text(
                                _isSwitchedOn_light ? 'on' : 'off',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                              )),
                              value: _isSwitchedOn_light,
                              onChanged: (bool value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isSwitchedOn_light = value;
                                  (print(value));
                                  // (print(_isSwitchedOn_light));
                                });
                              },
                              secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                //Gnav googlesizebar importจาก pub.dev
                bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                  color: Colors.green.shade900,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: GNav(
                        onTabChange: (index) {
                          setState(() {
                            _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
                          });
                        },
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade900,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        activeColor: Colors.white,
                        tabBackgroundColor: Colors.green.shade800,
                        tabBorderRadius: 15,
                        iconSize: 20,
                        gap: 30,
                        tabs: [
                          GButton(icon: Icons.dashboard, text: " dashboard"),
                          // GButton(icon: Icons.settings, text: " setting"),
                        ]),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: order.id)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.docs.first.reference.update({field: newValue})
            });
```

here replace **orders** with your **own collection reference key**, and replace **order.id** with your **switch id**, and replace **field** with your **firebase field name**. newValue will be true or false as your need.